# Need generate encoded request every time from Jmeter

Tags: javascript, performance, jmeter, performance-testing

When I record from Jmeter, I have encoded item in a request as follow

```
cGFyYW1ldGVyX3ZhbHVlPTEyMyZyZWd1bGFyX2V4cHJlc3Npb25fdmFsdWU9NDU2JmlzX3BvcF91cD1ZJmhlYWRlcl90eXBlPWFkdl9wb3BfdXA=
```

then I decoded found as follow

```
parameter_value=123&regular_expression_value=456&is_pop_up=Y&
header_type=adv_pop_up
```

Where as 123 is the parameter value (that is input value) and 456 is regular expression value.

How to pass these two values and encode request and send from jmeter?

Comment: capture these values and extract using regex and then pass it to next request

Comment: Question is not about extracting, how to pass those values to encode and send request from jmeter

Comment: You should look at Jmeter sampler options carefully(you haven't it seems). If its a standard encoding then Jmeter sampler has checkbox (encode checkbox) and if it is custom encoding then you can achieve it using java code or beanshell processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding. I.e. if you want to encode and send the following request line:

> parameter_value=**foo**&regular_expression_value=**bar**&is_pop_up=Y&header_type=adv_pop_up

You can use [__Beanshell()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell) function as

```
${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.Base64Encoder; Base64Encoder.encode("parameter_value=foo&regular_expression_value=bar&is_pop_up=Y&header_type=adv_pop_up");)}
```

`foo` and `bar` can also be JMeter Variables

```
${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.Base64Encoder; Base64Encoder.encode("parameter_value=${foo}&regular_expression_value=${bar}&is_pop_up=Y&header_type=adv_pop_up");)}
```

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide to learn more about the power of Beanshell.

If this function line seems to scary you can consider using [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/). There are 2 functions available in the [Standard Set](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/StandardSet) which can help you with Base64 encoding and decoding. They are:

- base64Encode
- base64Decode

See [JMeter Plugins Custom Functions](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/) documentation for more details.